# Slow down podcast playback speed

Tags: ios

How can I slow down podcast playback speed to 90% - 75% on my iPhone?

Comment: Are you using the Apple's Podcasts app? Please update the question to mention the app.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's [Podcasts](https://itunes.apple.com/app/podcasts/id525463029) app lets you slow down playback speed only to 50%. To slow down the playback speed, tap the indicated button to cycle between **1x**, **1.5x**, **2x** and **.5x** speed.

[image]

There are various 3rd party Podcasts app for iOS which lets you slow down the playback speed with much fine grained values. One such app is [Podbean Podcast App & Player](https://itunes.apple.com/app/podbean-podcast-app-player/id973361050). It lets you slow down the playback speed with granularity of 10%.

[image] [image]